# Trying to connect Hibernate to Azure MySQL server. Getting error "Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL"

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, spring

I'm new to developing web applications in general, and this is my first time trying to create one using Spring and Hibernate.

I have gone through a couple of tutorials and now I am starting to work on my own web application.

I am trying to setup Spring and Hibernate web application using pure java (no XML). I have set up Azure MySQL database and I want to connect hibernate to it.
I have created an `AppConfig` file in which I configured Hibernate and Spring, also I have a `db.properties` file with information for connecting.

This is a Maven project and I have added dependency for `mysql-connector-java`. I have also created a file `Main.java` in which I try to insert data into table to test if a connection is working. When I try to start the app I get following errors :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in hr.fer.opp.infiniteloop.config.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
    at hr.fer.opp.infiniteloop.testing.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in hr.fer.opp.infiniteloop.config.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:535)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL '"jdbc:mysql://infiniteloop.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/zalagaonica?useSSL=true&requireSSL=false";'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2167)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2158)
    ... 46 more
```

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages="hr.fer.opp.infiniteloop")
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    // set up variable to hold the properties
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    // set up a logger for diagnostics
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());


    // define a bean for ViewResolver
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new
    InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    // beans for hibernate
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("hr.fer.opp.infiniteloop.entity");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
}
```

**db.properties**

```
    #
    # JDBC connection properties
    #
    db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    db.url="jdbc:mysql://infiniteloop.mysql.database.azure.com:3306
    /zalagaonica?useSSL=true&requireSSL=false";
    db.user=username
    db.password=password
    #
    # Hibernate properties
    #
    hibernate.show_sql=true
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

**Main.java** main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new
                           AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

            AdminService adminService =
                           context.getBean(AdminService.class);

            // Add Admins
            adminService.add(new Admin("Admin1"));
            adminService.add(new Admin("Admin2"));

            // Get Admins
            List<Admin> admins = adminService.getAdmins();

            for(Admin admin : admins)
                          System.out.println(admin.getUsername());

            context.close();

}
```

Also I used this code in the same project to verify that I can connect to the database using this JDBC driver and code worked.

```
public static void main (String[] args)  throws Exception{
        // Initialize connection variables.
        String host = "infiniteloop.mysql.database.azure.com";
        String database = "zalagaonica";
        String user = "username";
        String password = "password";

        // check that the driver is installed
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("MySQL JDBC driver NOT detected in library path.", e);
        }

        System.out.println("MySQL JDBC driver detected in library path.");

        Connection connection = null;

        // Initialize connection object
        try
        {
            String url = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s/%s", host, database);

            // Set connection properties.
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("user", user);
            properties.setProperty("password", password);
            properties.setProperty("useSSL", "true");
            properties.setProperty("verifyServerCertificate", "true");
            properties.setProperty("requireSSL", "false");

            // get connection
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Failed to create connection to database.", e);
        }
        if (connection != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Successfully created connection to database.");

            // Perform some SQL queries over the connection.
            try
            {
                // Drop previous table of same name if one exists.
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inventory;");
                System.out.println("Finished dropping table (if existed).");

                // Create table.
                statement.execute("CREATE TABLE inventory (id serial PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), quantity INTEGER);");
                System.out.println("Created table.");

                // Insert some data into table.
                int nRowsInserted = 0;
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO inventory (name, quantity) VALUES (?, ?);");
                preparedStatement.setString(1, "banana");
                preparedStatement.setInt(2, 150);
                nRowsInserted += preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                preparedStatement.setString(1, "orange");
                preparedStatement.setInt(2, 154);
                nRowsInserted += preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                preparedStatement.setString(1, "apple");
                preparedStatement.setInt(2, 100);
                nRowsInserted += preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println(String.format("Inserted %d row(s) of data.", nRowsInserted));

                // NOTE No need to commit all changes to database, as auto-commit is enabled by default.

            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                throw new SQLException("Encountered an error when executing given sql statement.", e);
            }      
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Failed to create connection to database.");
        }
        System.out.println("Execution finished.");
```

I have looked every stack overflow post about this topic and non did provide me with the answer.

Comment: Is your database in local storage?

Comment: No it is not.. @AvijitBarua

Comment: Can you post a  screenshot of your project structure ?